# Handling activity / application restore when Android destroys application for memory

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I just ran into a crash that I'm not sure the proper way to handle. My app has several "managers" to cache off some information used across the entire app. These are stored my own implementation of an Application class.

When my app is minimized, and another application launches, there's the possibility that the phone will be low on memory from extended use of numerous other apps. If that's the case, my app could be cleared from memory.

Upon relaunching my app, the activity that was last opened is attempted to be re-created. However my managers in the overall application are now null, and my app runs into NullPointerExceptions when trying to reference information from them.

How should I go about this scenario? Is there a way to prevent the last activity from being opened if my app was seemingly destroyed for memory for other apps? I would be okay with the application re-starting from scratch (to re-initialized my managers and cached data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is a single variable (an OAuth Token) that I rely on the make sure the user is logged into my app, I decided to add a check to see if it's null in each activity's onCreate. I don't have a single valid case where it should be null (aside from being at the launcher activity), so it made sense to check that.

If that token is null, I just start up a LauncherActivity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` so that all previous activities on the stack are cleared, and the application essentially starts back up from scratch.

Hope this finds others with similar situations useful.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    manager = MyApplication.class.cast(getApplicationContext()).getManager();
    Token token = manager.getToken();
    if(null == token) {
        Log.w("MyActivity", "Token is null");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LauncherActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the initializaion of manager = MyApplication.class.cast(getApplicationContext()).getManager();

Comment: and Token is not importing too

Answer (score 0):

You could have each activity's `onCreate()` tell the Application to initialize itself if it's not already initialized.

Comment: I was thinking about this - unfortunately I have quite a few maps (and maps with maps) with various data that the last activity is looking for. So even after re-creating my global caches, they're still empty and my app is looking for specific maps. I'll pretty much need to just finish() everything back to my home screen to use network calls to retrieve necessary information. I'd honestly prefer some way to just not let android try to get the top activity if the entire activity gets destroyed.